# Bootstrap Nav Bar drop down wont open on click or hover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[image: I want this to have the dropdown open on click]The dropdown nav element won't work for whatever reason(meaning the dropdown doesn't come up) I've looked over all the bootstrap documentation I could find. I originally thought the problem was that I was using it in react-router dom with nav links. I realized I should try putting it into a regular HTML doc to confirm this, and low and behold it still doesn't work...

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" activeClass="active">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" activeClass="active">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" activeClass="active" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" activeClass="active">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" activeClass="active">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" activeClass="active">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" activeClass="active">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** There is one problem in your code, You have used `data-toggle` but it should be `data-bs-toggle`

It should be

```
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" activeClass="active" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

instead of

```
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" activeClass="active" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

**2)** Be sure to include bootstrap JS file

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**3)** You should change `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle`  and `data-target` to `data-bs-target` on the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" activeClass="active">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" activeClass="active">Link</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" activeClass="active" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" activeClass="active">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" activeClass="active">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" activeClass="active">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" activeClass="active">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I will, but it didn't solve it I meant the drop down on the dropdown anchor tag in the nav bar. Like when it is on pc not mobile

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I added a picture I want that to display the drop down menu when I click it

Comment: It is displaying as expected [see here](https://imgur.com/a/wQzqYCi)

Comment: You have added a class `navbar-expand-lg` which will only expand if the screen size matches size defined in bootstrap `lg`

Comment: Its not for me I am putting the full code in the question now please tell me If it still works for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236715/discussion-between-wayne-and-hr01m8055).

Comment: See the latest `3rd` point also and updated example. Hope it helps